# MySQL remote access allowance

Tags: mysql, windows, ip, remote-access

Hi have installed MySQL on my Windows server 2012.

Everything is fine and I can connect to the database on the local server. But I was wondering how I can allow remote connections such as my home computer. I prefer to have a list of IP's to allow connections to, rather then allowing all remote connections.

Any solutions?

Regards

Comment: Having a list of allowed IPs isn't that much of a security gain. For someone who wants to attack you it isn't hard to change his/her IP to whatever is accepted.

Comment: mysql user syntax is `username@domain_or_ip`. [CREATE USER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

Comment: @Kritzefitz low security is better then no security.

Comment: @Radin-fiveOnefiveHighgate That's right. I just wanted to note.

Answer (score -1):

When creating a MySQL user account, specify the IP address that is allowed, in the account's `Host:` field.

Example:

Instead of creating `user@localhost` (only local connection allowed) or `user@%` (any connection allowed), use `user@ip.address` (only ip.address connection allowed).